# Loop Cut Coordination technique

Tags: modeling

A while ago I following a tutorial which demonstrates how to position loop cuts in specific places using loop cut, Grab X-Y-Z and giving a specific numeric so the lop cut can relocate to the desired position.

I'm trying to use the same technique on this mesh, I have added one loop cut on one of the triangular faces. Which I then used the factor to designate the position. But when I try to use the technique as the instructor, instead of the loop cut moving, the whole face moves and deforms. In this case, should I just use the factor after doing a loop cut on each individual face, or am I complicating things trying to do what the video instructor is doing?

Thank you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSR6bVFe5LM

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial, the side 'rails' down which the edge is moving are parallel, so a translation (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, for example) is equivalent to a slide (<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>). On a triangle, that's not the case.

You can make a numerical entry for the distance of a translation, because all affected components move by the same amount. But you can't, by distance, for a slide, because vertices in a sliding loop will move different distances, depending on the location of adjacent vertices on the rails.

Instead, a numerical entry for a slide represents the *fraction* of the distance to adjacent vertices, where 0 is the current position, and distances to adjacent vertices are mapped to  1 and -1.

You might be able to use that fraction, with a bit of mental arithmetic, but usually, for accuracy, I find myself <kbd>G</kbd> translating single vertices down edges using [Custom Orientations](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html) derived from them where necessary, and as far as possible thinking like a carpenter.. finding ways to transfer measurements from one part of a model to another.

Comment: Oh. I finally understand why loopcut position is relative and *cannot* be an absolute value :). Always learning.

Comment: Hi Robbin. 

Thanks for your reply, in this instance I believe it's not too tedious to use the Fraction option, although it would be convenient if there was a way to achieve this using a method on the triangles.

Thanks for your insight.